# Executing T-SQL Command with Multiple Variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, execute

I am having an issue I honestly have no idea how to fix.

I have a query that is doing a loop basically, with a execute command. And my results are being returned with blanks, where the statement would have a blank set of data basically.

I.E. I get multiple result sets returned as expected, and a whole lot returned with no data in them.

Please give me a hand, I really am completely lost and its driving me mad here.

```
DECLARE @CustomerRegion NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @Groups NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @BRANCH NVARCHAR(7)
DECLARE @getid CURSOR

SET @BRANCH = N'Patleys'

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
   SELECT   
       [Main_Reporting].[dbo].[Sales].[Customer Region],
       [Main_Reporting].[dbo].[Sales].[Groups]
   FROM 
       [Main_Reporting].[dbo].[Sales]

OPEN @getid

FETCH NEXT FROM @getid INTO @CustomerRegion, @Groups

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC ('SELECT [Branch]
                  ,[cust-number]
                  ,[Customer Region]
                  ,[Groups]
           FROM [Main_Reporting].[dbo].[Sales]
           WHERE      -- Missed     
               [Customer Region] != ''1''
               AND [Customer Region] = ''' + @CustomerRegion + '''
               AND [Groups] = ''' + @Groups + '''
           GROUP BY 
               [Branch], [cust-number]
               , [Customer Region], [Groups]
           ORDER BY 
               MAX([invoice-date]) DESC')

    FETCH NEXT FROM @getid INTO @CustomerRegion, @Groups
END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

--Edited--

Sorry I am doing the Loop because its going to Generate a file output with the possible combinations of Group and Customer Region.

So I will have in this instance 10 different files, each with the data that is Distinct for Group and Customer Region.

Rather than generating several scripts each loop would run, and then output to a file and move onto the next. This way i thought would be better in that if I added anything new, E.I. we have a new group join in, we would have another report generate with its unique data in it.

Hope this helps, sorry for the vague explination earlier.

Comment: First of all you miss WHERE statement in exec

Comment: Always a good idea to `PRINT` your dynamic query first, to see what you will actually be running .. replace the `EXEC` with `PRINT` and confirm that your SQL does what you expect it to.

Comment: Why are you doing this in a loop? This could be written easily and much more sanely as a proper set based query.

Comment: You're selecting `CustomerRegion` and `Groups` from the same tables as you use in the loop inside the `EXEC` - that makes no sense at all. And the `@Branch` is not used at all ....... ***what exactly*** are you trying to achieve here?? Please explain in **plain English** what your objective is - maybe then we can help......

Comment: Sorry the branch is for going forward.

Comment: What is basically happening is, Im doing this at this point, and its going to generate a output to txt or csv file, for each of the possible outputs. The Group / Customer Region Combination will generate several unique sets of data which i want to have in seperate files.

Comment: esoteric-screen-name, This was just the best I could think of that Im doing the loop for multiple file outputs (Sorry wasnt in intial question). I honestly dont know of better way in this case, I havent played around with loops before, been reading up where I can and doing this on the fly as i learn it.

Comment: So did the where fix it or not?  If not then explain what is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include your where criteria in your cursor.  " [Customer Region] != ''1''" is in the select inside the cursor.  When you happen upon a record where the customer region is 1, you get blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are completely lost

- Don't ever use SET @BRANCH = N'Patleys'
- No where
- Loop over every value and have a group by on the value - no need for
  a loop

One select - no loop - no cursor

```
SELECT [Branch], [cust-number], [Customer Region], [Groups]
FROM   [Main_Reporting].[dbo].[Sales]
where  [Customer Region] != '1'
GROUP BY [Branch], [cust-number], [Customer Region], [Groups]
ORDER BY MAX([invoice-date]) DESC')
```

Comment: Sorry Blam, the reason for the loop i forgot to add. its going to generate multiple files, based on unique combinations.

Comment: Then be clear in the question.  Even so get your values in the cursor rather than re-query for data inside the loop.  You need to state describe what you want to do as I suspect you are not taking an optimal approach,

Answer (score 0):

OK Thank you Will, your info helped me out there. Defining the Where in my cursor seemed to get everything I needed correctly.

I pulled the Where in Both cases so I get the various Outputs I wanted, correctly when doing 2 or 3 seperately.

So basically My script now appears as such.

```
DECLARE @CustomerRegion NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @Groups NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @BRANCH NVARCHAR(7)
DECLARE @getid CURSOR

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
   SELECT   
       [Main_Reporting].[dbo].[Sales].[Customer Region],
       [Main_Reporting].[dbo].[Sales].[Groups]
   FROM 
       [Main_Reporting].[dbo].[Sales]
WHERE   [Customer Region] != ''1''

OPEN @getid

FETCH NEXT FROM @getid INTO @CustomerRegion, @Groups

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC ('SELECT [Branch]
                  ,[cust-number]
                  ,[Customer Region]
                  ,[Groups]
           FROM [Main_Reporting].[dbo].[Sales]
           WHERE   [Customer Region] != ''1''
               AND [Customer Region] = ''' + @CustomerRegion + '''
               AND [Groups] = ''' + @Groups + '''
           GROUP BY 
               [Branch], [cust-number]
               , [Customer Region], [Groups]
           ORDER BY 
               MAX([invoice-date]) DESC')

    FETCH NEXT FROM @getid INTO @CustomerRegion, @Groups
END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

Now Just working on the Multiple XLS outputs :)

Thanks for the assist guys and girls.